# Node.js + Prometheus - Target Down Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am running a node applications locally. It runs on `http://localhost:3002` using **prom-client** i can see the metrics at the following endpoint **http://localhost:3002/metrics**.

I've setup prometheus in a docker container and ran it.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

**prometheus.yml**

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:3002']
        labels:
          service: 'my-service'
          group: 'production'
rule_files:
  - 'alert.rules'
```

---

```
docker build -t my-prometheus .
docker run -p 9090:9090 my-prometheus
```

When i navigate to `http://localhost:9090/targets` it shows

> Get http://localhost:3002/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3002: connect:
>   connection refused

[image]

Can you please tell me what im doing wrong here. node app is running on localhost at that port becasue when i go to `http://localhost:3002/metrics` i can see the metrics.

Answer (score 3):

When you are inside a container, you cannot access the localhost directly. You will need to add docker.for.mac.localhost to your prometheus.yml file. See below:

Your Job in prometheus.yml file.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

```
# metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
# scheme defaults to 'http'.

static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:9090']
- targets: ['docker.for.mac.localhost:3002']
```

Answer (score 1):

and for windows, it would be

```
- job_name: 'spring-actuator'
metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
scrape_interval: 5s
static_configs:
  - targets: ['docker.for.win.localhost:8082']
```

Answer (score 0):

The applications are not in the same network. Firstly, you can create docker image from your node application too. When running docker images, network( `--net`) parameter should be passed to both images.

Run prometheus app:

`docker run --net basic -p 9090:9090 my-prometheus`

Run nodejs app:

`docker run --net basic -p 8080:8080 my-node-app`

Now, the applications run in the same network that is called `basic`. So the prometheus application can access the `http://localhost:3002/metric` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to localhost...success

```
global:
scrape_interval: 5s
scrape_timeout: 5s
evaluation_interval: 1s
scrape_configs:
```

- job_name: prometheus
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  static_configs:

  - targets:
    ['127.0.0.1:9090']
- job_name: class
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']